# Given the LDAP name, how do I find the Azure Graph API name

Tags: azure, ldap, azure-ad-graph-api

I am used to access my customers AD's via LDAP.

Now I have a customer with their data in Azure AD, and I can not find any explanation for what the properties are called in Azure given that I know what the name is in LDAP.

As an example is the old `title` now called `JobTitle`, `postalAddress` is now `StreetAddress` and `objectGUID` seems to have been changed into `ImmutableId` and have been base64 encoded.

Is there anywhere I can find a list where I can see what properties corresponds to something else in Azure Graph API?

I have previously found [something like that](http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm) when I started out with LDAP at the following url: http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm

Comment: did you find the info you were looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately no @asgs, I havn't been able to find a list :/